# When numbers plugged in - this expression evaluates to zero, but otherwise will not evaluate to zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, syntax

I have the following code:

```
COV1 = {{a1,0},{0,a2}}; COV2 = {{b1,0},{0,b2}};
T = MatrixPower[MatrixPower[COV1,1/2],-1]*MatrixPower[MatrixPower[COV1,1/2]*COV2*MatrixPower[COV1,1/2],1/2]*MatrixPower[MatrixPower[COV1,1/2],-1];
Thalf = 1/2*{{1,0},{0,1}} + 1/2*T;
COV3 = Thalf*COV1*Transpose[Thalf]+{{0,t},{t,0}}
d1 = Sqrt[Tr[COV1 + COV2 - 2*MatrixPower[MatrixPower[COV1,1/2]*COV2*MatrixPower[COV1,1/2],1/2]]]
d2 =Sqrt[Tr[COV1 + COV3 - 2*MatrixPower[MatrixPower[COV1,1/2]*COV3*MatrixPower[COV1,1/2],1/2]]]*2
Simplify[d2 - d1]
```

When I plug in numbers such as

```
a1 = 5, a2 = 7, b1 = 9, b2 = 45
```

The last expression evaluates to zero. However when I leave everything as variable, the expresssion doesn't reduce to zero. However, it should. What is going on?

My guess is I need to impose conditions like a1, a2, b1, b2 are strictly positive reals -- but I don't know how to do this.

Also I tried this powerExpand trick I found -- it didn't work (perhaps I used it incorrectly?)

Comment: `Simplify[d2 - d1, Assumptions -> Element[{a1, a2, b1, b2}, Reals]]`

Comment: ah, this still didnt work

Comment: Your final expression is quite complicated. Perhaps mathematica can't do further simplification. You can try `FullSimplify` and `Assumptions->{a1>0, a2>0,b1>0,b2>0}`.

Comment: ya, i tried fixing 3 variables, (a2 = 3, b1 = 5, b2 = 7) and working with the resulting expression -- it still doesn't simplify to zero

Comment: @yoshi for a given assignment you can do `RootReduce[
 FullSimplify[(d2 - d1) /. {b1 -> 5, b2 -> 3}, (a1 | a2) \[Element] 
    PositiveReals] /. {a1 -> 4, a2 -> 6}
 ]`.

Comment: Going further, let `eqn = FullSimplify[(d2 - d1), (a1 | a2 | b1 | b2) \[Element] 
    PositiveReals];` and `FullSimplify[
 eqn[[1]]^2 == eqn[[2]]^2, (a1 | a2 | b1 | b2) \[Element] 
  PositiveReals]` gives `a1 + a2 + Sqrt[a1 b1] + Sqrt[a2 b2] == 
 Sqrt[a1 (a1 + b1 + 2 Sqrt[a1 b1])] + Sqrt[
  a2 (a2 + b2 + 2 Sqrt[a2 b2])]`. I don't know how to prove this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `a1,a2,b1,b2` are all positive, we can substitute them with other numbers $x^2, y^2, z^2, w^2$.

```
FullSimplify[d2 - d1 /. {a1 -> x^2, a2 -> y^2, b1 -> z^2, b2 -> w^2},
 Element[{x,y,z,w}, PositiveReals]]

(* result: 0 *)
```

Comment: i think there's a bracket missing at the end, but ya, thanks!

Comment: @yoshi thanks, fixed.